# How can I align text input to the far right in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi how can I align my text input to the far far right of the colum?
The first image is what my current app looks like, and I dont want that(this is the default)

[image: This is what I dont want]

I want my input text to look like this, like in the second pic
[image: The one I want]

I want the top input text to be exactly align with the bottom text. How can I do that?

Here's my code below:

```
Column(

          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              width: 250,
              height: 40,
              child: TextFormField(
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                  decimal: true,
                ),
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9,.]'))
                ],
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      width: 0,
                      style: BorderStyle.none,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                //validator: numberValidator,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              "words",
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Comment: You want the numbers to start from the end, but you also want them to align with the 's' in 'words'?

Comment: Yes. Exactly that

Answer (score 1):

Please column wrap with Row like this

Row(childern:[Expanded(child:your column),SizedBox(width:50)])